# CakePHP: late row lookup

Tags: mysql, cakephp, innodb

We have a CakePHP query that is really starting to bog down our server. The problem is that a huge number of records are returned and paginated. If a user goes to the end of the pagination (page 60,000 for example) the queries take a huge amount of time and our cpu usage sky-rockets. Before we give up and cap the number of pagination records, we would like to at least try to make our query more efficient.

We know that the problem is late row lookup and we know that solutions exist (this one for example: https://explainextended.com/2011/02/11/late-row-lookups-innodb/), however we are having a hard time moving a standard CakePHP query to something that would help us.

This is our Cake query:

```
$pagination = array(
    'Sentence' => array(
        'fields' => $fields,
        'contain' => $contain,
        'conditions' => array(
            'text' => $text,
        ),
        'limit' => CurrentUser::getSetting('per_page'),
        'order' => "Sentence.id desc"
    )
);
```

$contain has several relations, two of which are more than one layer deep:

```
Array
(
    [Favorites_users] => Array
        (
            [fields] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id
                    [1] => username
                    [2] => group_id
                    [3] => level
                )

        )

    [SentencesList] => Array
        (
            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id
                )

        )

    [Transcription] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => username
                        )

                )

        )

    [Translation] => Array
        (
            [Transcription] => Array
                (
                    [User] => Array
                        (
                            [fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => username
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

We can get the base Sentence table info with this raw query:

```
SELECT  {$lFields}
FROM    (
        SELECT  {$fields}
        FROM    sentences AS Sentence
        ORDER BY
                id DESC
        LIMIT   10
        ) q
JOIN    sentences l
ON      l.id = q.id
ORDER BY
    q.id DESC
```

However, this doesn't get any of the relationships and Cake really disagrees with the output format.

So, is it possible to get Cake to make a query that will minimize late row lookup time?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! In different version problems can be solved in different ways.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Its a legacy 1.3 Cake app. Yeah, I know.....

Answer (score 0):

Pagination via `OFFSET` is painfully slow.  Figure out how to "remember where you left off".  [*More discussion*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) .